# \subsubsection command and xcolor package

Tags: sectioning, color, templates

I am using `xcolor` package to draw some colored tables. But I am having trouble with the `\subsubsection` command. 
When I block comment the colored tables and `xcolor` package, it works. 
When I do not use any `subsubsection`, it works.
But when I use both at the same time, I get the errors below. Any one knows the solution? Thank you.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.

<<to be read again>to be read again>

}

1.545 \subsubsection{Improved Bounds} I

n this part,

! Color stack action is missing.

<<to be read again>to be read again>

}

1.545 \subsubsection{Improved Bounds} I

n this part,
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I would guess that you have added color commands to the section title in such a way that they also appeared in the page  and corrupted the color stack. But without an example hard to guess and impossible to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 4):

The OP posted a minimal working example on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org). It turned out, that he used the `fbe_tez` package, which uses `\underbar` in its definition of the `\@sect`macro.

The line I refer to is

```
\edef\@svsec{\underbar{\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip 0.5em}}
```

As soon as the macro is patched such that it uses `\underline` instead, the error is gone.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\underbar}{\underline}{}{}
\makeatother
```

`\underbar` is actually defined using `\underline` but at the base line. From `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\underbar#1{\underline{\sbox\tw@{#1}\dp\tw@\z@\box\tw@}}
```

The error would go away as well if `\edef` would be replaced by `\def`.

The whole thread regarding this topic: [\subsubsection command and xcolor](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=20807).

Comment: I have suffered from this style file in my MSc thesis too. Thanks a bunch for fixing one of many issues!

Comment: @percusse With regards to [Numerating captions of subfigures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/621877), do you see any way to get this package updated? Do you know if somebody reported bugs so far?

Comment: Thank you, you are a hero. I have contacted the institute to update the template.