# Numerating captions of subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats, minipage

I have two figures to add into a single `figure` environment. When I use `subfigure`, I got the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.25         \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
```

I have searched the internet and tried to use packages `caption` and `subcaption` and use `subfloat` environment from package `subfig` they work fine for figures but `subfig`, `caption` and `subcaption` packages all overwrite format of `listoffigures` which is unexeptable. So I used `minipage` environment as in example below. But i can not get rid of numarating subfigures.

[image]

I want to have `a` and `b` for subfigures and don't have them in `listoffigures` and just `Figure 1.1` for all of them.

The style file `fbe_tez.sty` can be found in the link: http://www.fbe.boun.edu.tr/en/downloads/fbe_thesis.zip

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}    
\usepackage{styles/fbe_tez}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Graphics will be here

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

  \listoffigures

  \chapter{Chapter name}  

  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure1.png}
      \caption{1.graph caption.}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure2.png}
      \caption{2. graph caption.}
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{Figure caption.}
    \vskip\baselineskip % Leave a vertical skip below the figure
    \label{fig:sample}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete for a decade now. Instead, package `subcaption` should be used to do the job. In your case, it does not work, since the custom package file redefines a lot of internal commands. I would contact the maintainer and ask him for updates.

Comment: It's news to me that the `caption` and `subcaption` packages alter the format of the `List of Figures`.

Comment: So I am looking a way to change captions of `minipage` environment or I can use `caption` and `subcaption` packages but I need to overwrite its caption format. In example, I need Figure word for every item in `List of Figures` and a dot after figure number instead of colon.

Comment: Please read the comments in the style file, the maintainer is responsible to make the appearance apply to the rules. He will also ensure, that every student using the package doesn't run into the same problem as you.

Comment: @Johannes_B The custom package is made by my institute and it is very hard to reach who wrote it(Because he has not been a member of our institute since 2003). They even didn't correct old mistakes like:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/subsubsection-command-and-xcolor-package/61774#61774

Comment: A bit of searching got me to https://github.com/onurgu/BOUN-FBE-Thesis-Latex-Style

Comment: He is just the one who is responsible about the style file after the maintainer left the institute 12 years ago and his solution is combining subfigures and adding captions with MSPaint and add to latex as a single figure...

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It ignores your style file, but you can try if works with it.

If you do not want the numbers for subfigures, do not use caption. Here the two versions with minipage and subfigures.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}    
%\usepackage{styles/fbe_tez}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\usepackage{graphicx}


\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

  \listoffigures

  \chapter{Chapter name}  

  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure1.png}
      %\caption{1.graph caption.}
      1. graph caption.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure2.png}
      %\caption{2. graph caption.}
      2. graph caption.
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{Figure 1 caption.}
    \vskip\baselineskip % Leave a vertical skip below the figure
    \label{fig:sample}
  \end{figure}


  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure1.png}
        }
        \caption{Subfigure A}
        %\label{fig:subfig8}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure2.png}
        }
        \caption{Subfigure B}   
        %   \label{fig:subfig9}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Figure 2 caption.} 
    \label{fig:estfin}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result with subfigures
[image]

The result with subfigures
[image]

Comment: Beside the fact that i need the style file, using `caption` package changes format of captions and `list of figures` such as the colon instead of dot after figure number or removes the Figure words in `list of figures` which are unexceptable for me. I need to overwrite them to use `caption` package.

Comment: You can still use `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}`

Comment: If you want to use styles/fbe_tez additionally you need to save and restore the definitions of `\@caption` and `\@makecaption` so the caption package is happy with it. Afterwards you could restore the modifications to these commands, but using regular commands offered by the caption package instead. See my answer (since the code does not fit into this comment).

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the answer from Robert (see my comment there):

Load `style/fbe_tez` this way:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ORI@caption\@caption
\let\ORI@makecaption\@makecaption
\makeatother
\usepackage{styles/fbe_tez}
\makeatletter
\let\@caption\ORI@caption
\let\@makecaption\ORI@makecaption
\makeatother
```

This way the definitions of `\@caption` and `\@makecaption` will be saved and restored, so the re-definitions of these two macros done by style/fbe_tez will be lost. This makes the caption package happy, since it does not have to deal with unknown modifications of these macros.

Afterwards you could try to emulate the (lost) modifications by using regular commands offered by the caption package, e.g.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figure}{Figure #2.}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{table}{Table #2.}
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figure}
\captionsetup[table]{listformat=table}
```

or (when using caption3.sty v1.7 or newer)

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{fbe_tez}{\csname\captionlisttype name\endcsname\space#2.}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period,listformat=fbe_tez}
```

So in total we have Roberts answer code, modified:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\makeatletter
\let\ORI@caption\@caption
\let\ORI@makecaption\@makecaption
\makeatother
\usepackage{styles/fbe_tez}
\makeatletter
\let\@caption\ORI@caption
\let\@makecaption\ORI@makecaption
\makeatother
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figure}{Figure #2.}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{table}{Table #2.}
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figure}
\captionsetup[table]{listformat=table}

% When using caption3.sty v1.7 (or newer) the last five lines could
% get shortened to these two lines instead:
% \DeclareCaptionListFormat{fbe_tez}{\csname\captionlisttype name\endcsname\space#2.}
% \captionsetup{labelsep=period,listformat=fbe_tez}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

  \listoffigures

  \chapter{Chapter name}  

  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure1.png}
      %\caption{1.graph caption.}
      1. graph caption.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure2.png}
      %\caption{2. graph caption.}
      2. graph caption.
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{Figure 1 caption.}
    \vskip\baselineskip % Leave a vertical skip below the figure
    \label{fig:sample}
  \end{figure}


  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure1.png}
        }
        \caption{Subfigure A}
        %\label{fig:subfig8}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_figure2.png}
        }
        \caption{Subfigure B}   
        %   \label{fig:subfig9}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Figure 2 caption.} 
    \label{fig:estfin}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be simple solved by use `subcaptionbox` environments define in the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter name}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth}
\subcaptionbox{1. sub graph caption. \label{subfig:1a}}
              {\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{2. sub graph caption. \label{subfig:1b}}
              {\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\caption{Figure caption.}
\label{fig:sample}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]